# Magento Order gets closed when doing a partial refund with adjustment fee in it

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have an issue in magento enterprise as follows

1. Place an order with 3 items in it
2. Redeem some money from the
   customer's store credit when placing the order. For example if 200
   is the total order amount, 50 should be paid from the customer's
   store credit and 150 should be paid as normal payment.
3. Ship the order via backend
4. Create credit memo for any 1 item in the
   order.
5. Add 1 in the adjustment fee field in the credit memo form
6. Save the credit memo.

The credit memo is created successfully, but the order status becomes closed. Due to this I am not able to raise another credit memo next time If I need to refund any or the remaining items in the order. This issue happens only if customer has redeemed his store creid in the order amount.

Could somebody please help me on this?

Comment: If your an enterprise customer you can ask for support might be the fastest way to get an answer.

Comment: Yes, they gave me a patch for fixing this issue. The patch is PATCH_SUPEE-3894_EE_1.13.1.0_v2.sh

Comment: Yes, I could have dug into it, but this sounded right up EE support's alley, as Store Credit is EE CustomerBalance if memory serves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?